# Automated file transfer using challenge-response authentication method

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer, authentication, scp

Doing SCP to a remote server to put the files. While we do that, we need to authenticate to the remote server using the challenge-response authentication method where we have a separate authentication server:

```
For example

scp <Filename> admin@IP of REMOTE server:/Path

Challenge : 12345  Product ID:435432
Response :
```

It  asks for response (password) to complete the file transfer and  we need to copy the challenge and product ID created to the authentication server(server2) and get the response from that server and put that in the response field shown above. If the response is correct, it would continue with the file transfer else it would deny the transfer.

We are given challenge-response authentication option for security reasons.

I would like to do AUTOMATED FILE transfer using this method.

Comment: Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, hard to say. But this does sound like a task best suited for an [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script:

> Expect is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs
>   according to a script. Following the script, Expect knows what can be
>   expected from a program and what the correct response should be. An
>   interpreted language provides branching and high-level control
>   structures to direct the dialogue. In addition, the user can take
>   control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning
>   control to the script.

There are many sites proving `expect` script examples such as [this one](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/) and [this one](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Automating-with-Expect-Scripts). But the concept is fairly simple. Here is a basic “hello world” example from one o those example pages:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
expect "hello"
send "world"
```

That basically sets the script timeout to 10 seconds, it is `expect`ing the word “hello” to be entered and then it would send the word “world” back.

Wrap that basic concept in some Bash script logic and perhaps that will help you achieve your goal of creating an automated file transfer process using challenge-response authentication method.

Comment: Can u enlighten how can we add Expect script  for challenge Response Authentication coz I need to get the response from a different server and put the response to file transfer server to complete the file transfer. Its more kind of an interactive based authentication to be more precise

Comment: Because I have already installed and using Expect script, for a few users we are using default passwords but how it answers the interactive based authentication is the question ,coz  the response is generated on another server and I need to copy the response back to server 1 to complete the file transfer.